# Drupal 7 Theme multimple template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I work with drupal 7 . I have created custom theme and I want to use different templates for different pages

My site base  link is `http://localhost/new/drupal`  and I want to use template for 
`http://localhost/new/drupal/home` page , I have `page-home.tpl.php` file but it is not working

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Clear your cache ? then test it..

Comment: Yes , I did it, but not wirking

Comment: Change page-home.tpl.php to page--home.tpl.php

Comment: Thank you man, Please write this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7 page template is jut like that -

```
page--[NAME].tpl.php
```

Change the file name "page-home.tpl.php" to "page--home.tpl.php". Don't forget to clear cache.

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) is Drupal page template tutorial. Read this tutorial before started theme develop.